# Selecting columns of matrix based on binary vector

Tags: r

In one piece of my code, I need to select certain columns of my matrix based on binary matrix I have, and store it in the list, but I face with following problem. Does anybody know what's the problem? 
Here is my matrix and code:

```
    > data
         A  B  C  D
    [1,] 1  6 11 16
    [2,] 2  7 12 17
    [3,] 3  8 13 18
    [4,] 4  9 14 19
    [5,] 5 10 15 20

    > select<-c(1,0,1,0)

> p<-data[,select,  drop=FALSE]
> p
     A A
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 3
[4,] 4 4
[5,] 5 5
```

My expected output is :

```
> p
     A  C
[1,] 1 11
[2,] 2 12
[3,] 3 13
[4,] 4 14
[5,] 5 15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to convert it to a logical vector or else it will treat 1 and 0 as column numbers:

```
data[,as.logical(select), drop=F]
#   A  C
# 1 1 11
# 2 2 12
# 3 3 13
# 4 4 14
# 5 5 15
```

Comment: How to preserve also the column name?

Comment: @user2806363 Did you try it on your own data? Since you didn't make an easy way to copy/paste your data into R, josilber probably didn't add colnames to his test data. This method will preserve colnames.

Comment: @user2806363 I updated `data` to have column names -- this method of subsetting preserves column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try.
When you are just supplying `select` you are telling it to select columns by column number. 
When you are supplying `select==1` you are first getting a logical vector and using that to select columns.

```
data <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 5, dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
select <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
data[, select == 1]
##      A  C
## [1,] 1 11
## [2,] 2 12
## [3,] 3 13
## [4,] 4 14
## [5,] 5 15
```